# Как получить список всех элементов на странице из WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как получить список всех элементов на странице из элемента управления WebBrowser? Необходимо получить именно всех элементов, а не отдельные из них.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```cs
foreach (HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.All) {
    Console.WriteLine(elem.Id);
}
```

#### Ссылки по теме

- [WebBrowser.Document](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document?view=netframework-4.8)
- [HtmlDocument.All](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.all?view=netframework-4.8)
- [HtmlElement.Id](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.id?view=netframework-4.8)